# Nhibernate setting query time out period for commands and pessimistic locking

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, nhibernate

I wish to specify a specific command timeout (or LOCK_TIMEOUT) for an SQL and once this time out is reached an exception (or alert) has to be raised in nHibernate.
The following is an example pseudo-code what I have written:

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession()) {
    using (var sqlTrans = session.BeginTransaction()) {
        ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Foo));
        criteria.SetTimeout(5); //Here is the specified command timout, eg: property SqlCommand.CommandTimeout
        Foo fooObject = session.Load<Foo>(primaryKeyIntegerValue, LockMode.Force);
        session.SaveOrUpdate(fooObject);
        sqlTrans.Commit();
    }
}
```

In SQL server we used to achieve this using the following SQL:

```
BEGIN TRAN
SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 500   
SELECT * FROM Foo WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) WHERE PrimaryKeyID = 1000001
```

If PrimaryKeyID row would have locked in other transaction the following error message is being shown by SQL Server:

```
Msg 1222, Level 16, State 51, Line 3
Lock request time out period exceeded
```

Similarly I wish to show a lock time out or command time out information using nHibernate. Please help me to achieve this.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your C# code has a 5 second timeout specified, while it is 0.5 seconds in the SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve pessimistic locking you need to get the details of object using ICritiera.
The altered code is given below:

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession()) {
    using (var sqlTrans = session.BeginTransaction()) {
        ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Foo>();
        criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq(fieldOnWhichYouWishToGetTheLock, fieldValue));
        criteria.SetLockMode(LockMode.Upgrade);
        criteria.SetTimeout(5);
        Foo fooObject = (Foo)criteria.List<Foo>();
        //Make the changes to foo object and save as usual.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @NRao, the solution is working for me. Please let me know how to get lock on multiple fields as well.

Comment: Wouldn't the LockMode.Force in the original code already be doing the pessimistic locking?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether you could adapt [this approach](http://www.zvolkov.com/clog/2011/02/28/application-level-locks-with-nhibernate-and-sp_getapplock/) to your purposes? It wouldn't be automatic, of course. and it would mean the passed in resourceName would likely need to be a concatenation of your entity type and its PK.

Alternatively, [command_timeout](http://nhforge.org/wikis/reference2-0en/nhibernate-provided-ado-net-connection.aspx) looks promising, but I can't see a way to do that (for updates) in any way other than system wide.