# Is it possible to set Firebird WAIT timeout for transaction when using NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, timeout, firebird, wait

In my code I use NHibernate ISession.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted) to begin transaction. I'm using Firebird 2.5. Sometimes in multi-user environments deadlock occurs. It's expected. Problem is if I use Firebird's .NET provider directly I can set deadlock WAIT timeout or use NO WAIT option, but I use NHibernate and for a week now can't find way to do this. Any help, opinions, hints?

Comment: Check the answer to this [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130000/setting-the-right-transaction-isolation-mode-with-nhibernate-how-to). It gives you a hint on how to set the transaction isolation level.

Comment: Thanks for comment. But problem is not in IsolationLevel. In link you gave he most probably uses Snapshot isolation and that's why he gets exception. My problem is that I use ReadCommitted isolation and where deadlock occurs my code waits infinitely for completion. So I need to find a way to tell Firebird .NET provider wait timeout, or configure it to use NO WAIT option (i.e. give exception immediately rather than wait)

Comment: Not sure how to set NO WAIT, but have you tried to configure the timeout using the details of `Icriteria`? Check this [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102647/nhibernate-setting-query-time-out-period-for-commands-and-pessimistic-locking)

Comment: Looks very promising. Didn't  know NHibernate has LockMode. Thank you.

Comment: In my specific case ICriteria LockMode is of no use for me. It seems to not work very good with Firebird. CommandTimeout seems to be right answer if I can find a way to change it before ISession.Flush(). So right now I'm going to modify Firebird .NET provider to fit me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this very old [link](http://fhasovic.blogspot.com.br/2005/02/transaction-isolation-levels-in.html) you can do any of these:

1. use the predefined isolation levels by calling `public FbTransaction BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel)`
2. tune the transaction options more precisely by using this `BeginTransaction` overload: `public FbTransaction BeginTransaction(FbTransactionOptions)`

So probably you should use second option to set the no_wait parameter.
But you may want an updated version of the documentation, or you could have problem [like this guy](http://firebird.1100200.n4.nabble.com/Transaction-configuration-with-the-ADO-NET-Data-provider-for-Firebird-td2311603.html). Maybe look at [Jiří Činčura's blog](http://blog.cincura.net/tag/firebird/).